# There is an error while executing `VBoxManage`, a CLI used by Vagrant in windows 7

Tags: vagrant, vagrantfile

I am getting this error when I try to run "vagrant up" command.

```
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> default: Importing base box 'ubuntu/trusty64'...
There was an error while executing `VBoxManage`, a CLI used by Vagrant
for controlling VirtualBox. The command and stderr is shown below.

Command: ["import", "C:/Users/dell/.vagrant.d/boxes/ubuntu-VAGRANTSLASH-trusty64/20160610.0.0/virtualbox/box.ovf", "--vsys", "0", "--vmname", "ubuntu-cloudimg-trusty-vagrant-amd64_1466542004813_74377", "--vsys", "0", "--unit", "6", "--disk", "C:\\Users\\dell\\VirtualBox VMs\\ubuntu-cloudimg-trusty-vagrant-amd64_1466542004813_74377\\box-disk1.vmdk"]

Stderr: 0%...10%...20%...30%...40%...50%...60%...70%...80%...90%...100%
Interpreting C:\Users\dell\.vagrant.d\boxes\ubuntu-VAGRANTSLASH-trusty64\20160610.0.0\virtualbox\box.ovf...
OK.
0%...
Progress state: VBOX_E_FILE_ERROR
VBoxManage.exe: error: Appliance import failed
VBoxManage.exe: error: Could not create the imported medium 'C:\Users\dell\VirtualBox VMs\ubuntu-cloudimg-trusty-vagrant-amd64_1466542004813_74377\box-disk1.vmdk' (VERR_VD_VMDK_INVALID_FORMAT)
VBoxManage.exe: error: Details: code VBOX_E_FILE_ERROR (0x80bb0004), component ApplianceWrap, interface IAppliance
VBoxManage.exe: error: Context: "enum RTEXITCODE __cdecl handleImportAppliance(struct HandlerArg *)" at line 877 of file VBoxManageAppliance.cpp
```

Can anyone pease help me to understand tell why I am getting the above error when i run "vagrant up" command.

Comment: whats your virtual box version ? make sure to get a recent one

Comment: i have already got the latest version i.e. 5.0.22 of virtual box.

Comment: Please include your `Vagrantfile`.